# Find $\det(A^3B^2+A^2B^3)$ for $A,B$ s.t. $AB = BA$ given $\det A,\det B$.

Tags: determinant

If two matrices $A$ and $B$ are such that $AB = BA$ with $\det A = 1$ and $\det B = 0$, then what is $\det(A^3B^2 + A^2B^3)$ ?

Comment: Thanks man...!! Can you help me with this question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even without assuming commutativity, we see that
$$ A^3B^2+A^2B^3=(A^3B+A^2B^2)\cdot B$$
is singular.

Comment: How do we understand that the above relation of matrices is singular ?

Comment: @Soham: The kernel of $B $ is nontrivial (since $\det B=0$), and thus so is the kernel of $CB $, for any matrix $C $.

Answer (score 5):

We have that:
$$\det(A^3B^2 + A^2B^3) = \det(A^2B^2(A + B)) = \det(A^2B^2)\det(A + B) = (1)^2(0)^2\det(A + B) = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\text{det}(A^3B^2+A^2B^3) & = \text{det}A^2 \text{det} B^2\text{det}(A+B)\\
& = (\text{det}A)^2 (\text{det} B)^2\text{det}(A+B)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Could we get the value of the det if det B would not be 0 ?

Comment: @SohamSarkar probably not without some additional information.